# Sequence: Sup, Inf, LimSup and LimInf

Tags: calculus, analysis

Given the sequence: $ a_n = (n^2+3n+1)^{1/n}-1 $
. Find $ \sup(a_n) $ , $ \inf(a_n) $, $ \lim[\sup(a_n)] $ and $ \lim[\inf(a_n)] $ .

So at first I tried to make the set puting some numbers $ n = 1,2,3,4,... $ to see how the set of numbers $ a_n $ behaves:

$ Set{(a_n)} = \{4, \sqrt{11}-1, \sqrt[3]{19}-1, \sqrt[4]{29}-1, \dots\} $

It is easy to see that $ \sup(a_n) = 4 $ and $ \inf(a_n) = 0 $ but I cannot find a way to prove it

For instance I tried the Supremum Property:

$ \sup(a_n) = 4 \iff \forallε>0 : \sup(a_n) - ε < a_n \iff 4 - ε < (n^2+3n+1)^{1/n}-1 \iff (5-ε)^n < n^2+3n+1 \iff (1+(4 - ε))^n < n^2+3n+1 $

Then in the left part of the above inequality I tried Bernoulli's inequality which working it a little bit gave me that: $ n^2+(ε-1)n \ge 0 $

I am not sure though how to continue. Also I am not sure about whether $ \sup(a_n) = \lim[\sup(a_n)] $ and same for the $ \inf(a_n) $. Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

For each $n\in\Bbb N\setminus\{1\}$, you have $1\leqslant n^2+3n+1\leqslant n^3$, and therefore$$0=\sqrt[n]1^2-1\leqslant\sqrt[n]{n^2+3n+1}-1\leqslant\sqrt[n]n^3-1.$$So, since $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]n=1$, you have$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{n^2+3n+1}-1=0.$$So,$$\limsup_{n\in\Bbb N}\sqrt[n]{n^2+3n+1}-1=\liminf_{n\in\Bbb N}\sqrt[n]{n^2+3n+1}-1=0$$and, since it's a succession of non-negative numbers, $\inf\left\{\sqrt[n]{n^2+3n+1}-1\,\middle|\,n\in\Bbb N\right\}=0$. And it's not hard to see that $\sup\left\{\sqrt[n]{n^2+3n+1}-1\,\middle|\,n\in\Bbb N\right\}=5-1=4$.